Spring boot MongoDB incorrect query
I have a spring boot project, using MongoDB for the data storage. I am trying to query an individual object, GenericDataSet by its ID and tenant fields:
// Object
@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document
public class GenericDataSet extends TenantBaseModel<String> {

    private String name;

    private Long count;

    private List<Mapping> mappings;

}
//TenantBaseModel
@Setter
@Getter
public class TenantBaseModel<IDT> extends BaseModel<IDT> {

    private String tenant;

}
//BaseModel
@Component
@Getter
@Setter
public class BaseModel<IDT> {

    @MongoId(FieldType.OBJECT_ID)
    private IDT id;
    private Instant created_at = Instant.now();
    private Instant updated_at = Instant.now();
    private String created_by;
    private String updated_by;
}

Where my Query is:
@Query(value = "{ '_id' : ObjectId(?0), 'tenant' : ?1 }")
Optional<M> findById(String id, String tenant);

The following query works when checking in MongoDB atlas: {tenant: '66607f5c8f33db17c25fd2e3', _id: ObjectId('6662c0fdb520086e88c2410e')}
Why is it my spring boot query generates:
 { "_id" : { "$oid" : "666c1a51389e58386b99c42f"}, "tenant" : "666180169082ba03c1da380b"}

Which returns a 404, since the query is incorrect

That query looks about the same, except for the different values.

How do you know that your code is generating that query? Did you use Spring's debugging, enabled with this org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate: DEBUG?

Apologies for the reply delay; wasn't working!  Yes @AndrewL , setting that to DEBUG allowed me to see the query
